# Quoting a song in an essay title

Tags: citations, mla

I want to use a song lyric as a portion of my title for an essay. Obviously, I have to cite that those words are not my own, but how would I go about doing that? Do I use parenthetical documentation in my title (I am using MLA format) or do I just make a mention of it somehow on my Works Cited page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just put it in your works cited page. If the lyric is popular enough ("Hit me, baby, one more time", for example), your reader will probably know where the lyric is from without even having to read the back of your essay. Otherwise, a simple mention will cover you from any angry Oasis lawyers :)